# Solid-state AC load switching for both line and neutral wires

Tags: switches, solid-state-relay, triac

The common TRIAC circuits for switching AC loads cut only one wire (line).
I need to cut both (line and neutral). Is there a configuration to achieve this?

Even most encapsulated solid-state relays cut only one wire.

Comment: How fast do you need to switch? Cycle by cycle or once ever few minutes or???

Comment: Why do you need to cut both?  It's rare but not unheard of.  Challenge is you have to drive two gates with small voltages that are 120V apart.

Comment: @mkeith, every few minutes

Comment: @KH, this is a request of the customer to be sure to cut the line wire (there is no way to be sure which wire is the line at home)

Comment: Can you use a relay?

Comment: @mkeith, of course. But the question is about a solid-state solution...

Comment: Triacs leak current. If the concern is about electrical safety, then semiconductor devices may not be the best choice.

Comment: "*... this is a request of the customer to be sure to cut the line wire.*" This sounds as though the customer thinks that this specification will somehow make the device safer. It's hard to see how this could be the case as one device could fail without detection. You can't rely on triacs for safety. They can fail short-circuit or open-circuit. Challenge the customer for their reasoning. The other problem is that most switching arrangements require a current path to the other line to turn the triac on. If there is a switch in the other line you may not be able to turn on either.

Comment: Yes, and at such a low switching rate a relay isn't a bad option.  Also why are you assuming you can't identify the neutral?  Are plugs non polarized where you live or you want to account for the home electrical being installed wrong?  Does the device have a ground connection or just hot and neutral?

Comment: @KH, here in Italy the plugs are not polarized

Comment: Well it's not impossible to do it in solid state but its kind of an advanced engineering project because you have to have isolated gate control.  You need a control circuit that can safely communicate with both ends of the voltage spectrum.  Leakage current aside, one advantage to triacs is they only need a pulse and they accept positive or negative, so in theory you could isolate the gate with a transfomer and pulse it through that.  Another option is to attach a little(~5v) supply to each line and pulse them through an optoisolator driven by your separate control voltage.